# Редактор Wordpress добавляет и удаляет тег <p>. Как это отключить?

Tags: php, wordpress, wysiwyg, админка

Редактор автоматически добавляет теги p 
Чтобы это оключить в шаблон страницы добавил

```
<?php 
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); // Отключаем автоформатирование 

the_content(); ?>
```

Но теперь при переключении между вкладками "Визуально" и "Текст" теги p удаляются.

**Как отключить для шаблона страницы и автоматическое добавление и автоматическое удаление тегов p?**

Comment: http://wpcrux.com/blog/disable-wpautop/ or document onload jQuery('p:empty').remove();

Answer (score 1):

Добавь этот код не в шаблон страницы, а в functions.php

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема была с shortcodes, которая никак не лечилась отключением этого фильтра:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Пришлось протыкать в wp-include/default-filters.php много фильтров пока понял что дело в:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_blocks', 9 );
```

Что с этим делать уже думайте сами =)

WP был последней версии(5.4) на момент написания комментария.